# AWS IOT Analytics export to S3 encrypting in public bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-iot-analytics

I have a device connected to IOT core and sending data through IOT Analytics for processing. The dataset is exported to an S3 bucket. The S3 bucket as set as public, encryption disabled and has a bucket policy allowing public access but everytime the dataset is updated from IOT Analytics it is being encrypted, ignoring my bucket level settings. I've tested that the policy is working as expected if I manually upload a file to the bucket so it seems to be IOT Analytics that is causing this but there doesn't seem to be any options to manage this in the Console at least....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

IoT Analytics does not encrypt the data but encodes the data using base64.  IoT Analytics is intended to be used to transform/enrich data and to be queried with datasets after the data is stored in datastore. The data stored in S3 can be used with a downstream application for further processing or presentation to end-users.

If you need to decode the data you can follow the below steps

a. To gunzip the .gz file and replace it with the decompressed file:
gunzip -v filename.json.gz

--> Overwrites gzip file with filename.json which is base64 encoded (not human readable).

b) To base64 decode:
base64 --decode filename.json